# Cmd-' for increasing the quotation level doesn't work in mail

Tags: keyboard, mail.app, shortcut

I am using macOS Catalina (10.15.7) in my MacBook Pro 15-inch (2018). The problem is that `Cmd-'` in composing new email doesn't work. The keys are registered with proper modifier (checked via Karabiner-EventsViewer), the `Cmd-Opt-'` for decreasing quote level works as expected, only the shortcut mentioned above doesn't work.

Does anyone have any idea what I can check more and how to solve this issue?

Comment: Does it show correctly in the Format > Quote Level menu? idk of a fix if it does & I'm guessing me saying "it works fine for me" is not much help either ;-) Maybe try changing the command in keyboard prefs, to see if it's the combo or the command itself that's failing.

Comment: In the menu it displays correctly.

Comment: I'd test with a different key command. If that works, then something else must be intercepting it first.

Comment: @Tetsujin do you have any instruction how I can change the shortcuts in Mail.app?

Comment: Same as in any app, see https://support.apple.com/en-euro/guide/mac-help/mchlp2271/10.15/mac/10.15